# How to get rid of extra white space within a wrapper

Tags: html, css, wrapper

[image: Example]

As you can see on the example picture, there is some type of white space above the "news" header (padding? margin?) I have tried messing around with padding-top, margin-top but nothing I did would get rid of the white space. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="news_wrapper">
    <div id="newsheader">
        <p>News</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <p>"News Post 1"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <p>"News Post 2"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <p>"News Post 3"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
        <p>"News Post 4"</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#news_wrapper {
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
width: 650px;
height: auto;
margin: 6px;
}

#newsheader {
background-color: Black;
color: white;
width: auto;
margin: 0px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
font: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
text-transform: bold;
}

.news {
display: block;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your css

```
#newsheader p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with your `margin: auto`

I generally use `margin: 0 auto` for this effect.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, just tried and nothing changes. Thanks though!

Comment: Oops, sorry think I was zoned at work when I answered you. What I meant was remove the whole margin: auto. I meant to say that I have used margin: 0 auto to get the centering effect which you seem to not want in you implementation. Dunno if this is gonna work, but just to clarify.